# Error while syncing in Pocket (ReadItLater)

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I am using [Pocket](http://getpocket.com) 3.0.1 on Ubuntu (12.04 64-bit) which is fully patched. When I try to sync I get the below error. I sent a mail to Pocket, but there was no response. What could be the reason for the below error?

> Timestamp: Friday 22 February 2013 10:02:38  IST
>   Error: TypeError: title is undefined
>   Source File: jar:file:///home/praveensripati/.mozilla/firefox/wd4htjcr.default/extensions/isreaditlater@ideashower.com.xpi!/components/RILsync.js
>   Line: 248
>
> Timestamp: Friday 22 February 2013 01:39:50  IST
>   Warning: nsIJSON.decode is deprecated.  Please use JSON.parse instead.
>   Source File: jar:file:///home/praveensripati/.mozilla/firefox/wd4htjcr.default/extensions/isreaditlater@ideashower.com.xpi!/components/RILsync.js
>   Line: 361

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox has dropped support of nsIJSON.decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIJSON#decode%28%29).